# Ellipse polar equation relative to foci.

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates

I need to derive the ellipses polar equation relative to one of it's foci.

My starting point is the ellipses polar equation relative to the ellipses center:

$$r(\theta) = \frac{a·b}{\sqrt({(b·cos( \theta ) + (a·cos( \theta))}}\tag 1$$

From equation $(1)$, I want to derive the ellipses polar equation relative to one of it's foci, which is given by:
$$r(\theta) = \frac{a·(1-e^2)}{1+- e·cos(\theta)} \tag 2$$

I want to know how to derive equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$.

Comment: Not the best starting point. Rather, I suggest that you go back to the definition of an ellipse involving its focus and directrix.

Comment: The polar equation should read $$r = \frac{a b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 \theta+b^2\cos^2 \theta}}$$